# recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy does not work if iPhone is in place

Tags: c#, outlook

I developed an Addin to process Accepting and Declining Appointments automatically. Therefore I am checking the availability for the Appointment Request by using:

recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy

This works well as soon as I use Outlook but as soon as I have my iPhone running I run into following situation:

- In the moment my iPhone receives the request it is inserted as tentative Appointment in my calendar which gets synced with the server.
- When outlook runs now the recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy for the request it is always already tentative blocked, which the Appointment the request is for.

I tried already to set the status of the appointment to "Free" by using appItem.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olFree; but the result of recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy does not change. Probably because it is retrieved from the server and not from my local calendar.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design - pending meeting requests are processed to create tentative appointments. Once the user processes them, they are either deleted (if the user declines) or are replaced with the intended f/b value.

Comment: But how do I check if I am available at the time for that request - any idea?